# Is Thread::Pool::Simple naturally slower than Thread::Pool or is it my mistake?

Tags: linux, perl, threadpool

We've been having trouble building Thread::Pool on the latest versions of Ubuntu so we rewrote the code to use Thread::Pool::Simple instead, because that Perl module comes prepackaged with the distribution.

However, we discovered that no matter how many threads we run in the pool, it doesn't keep up with the message load anymore. In fact, it is running about 10x slower than it used to.

I read over the Thread::Pool::Simple code quickly and one thing jumped out at me: it makes a lot of calls to `yield()` which in Linux 2.6/3.0 systems is an awful, horrible idea.

What our little script does is read messages from an ActiveMQ message queue and processes them into our database system. With Thread::Pool this kept up easily, making 8 DB connections and writing in parallel. with Thread::Pool::Simple it seemed to work at first but the queue length just kept rising because it couldn't keep up.

Does anyone else have experience with these two versions of Perl thread pools?
Am I making some obvious mistake with the use of Thread::Pool::Simple?